# Tap events not working on touch devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, click, touch, prototype

I have a game where by random tickets fall from the top of the canvas. The aim is to click the tickets as they fall. Everything works on desktop but the the click events are not working on mobile. Below is the snippet of code responsible for the click event. Can anyone show me how to rewrite this in order to get the tap/touch events firing on touch devices?

```
/**
 * Global game events
 */
var GameEvents = (function () {
    function GameEvents() {
    }
    GameEvents.ON_PRESS_START = "ON_PRESS_START";
    GameEvents.ON_TIME_UP = "ON_TIME_UP";
    GameEvents.ON_TICKET_CLICKED = "ON_TICKET_CLICKED";
    GameEvents.ON_SUBMIT_SCORE = "ON_SUBMIT";
    return GameEvents;
}());


    /**
     * Start!
     */
    SceneMain.prototype.onPressStart = function () {
        // start the particles
        this._particles.start();
        this._particles.setInteraction(this.onTicketClicked.bind(this));
        this._score = 0;
        this._$scoreValue.text(0);
        // start the timer
        this._secondsRemaining = this._layout.getLayoutParams().time_limit;
        this._$timeValue.text(this._layout.getLayoutParams().time_limit);
        this._timer = new DelayCall(this.onTick.bind(this), 1000, DO.Core.Time.juggler, this._layout.getLayoutParams().time_limit, this.onTimeUp.bind(this));
        this._timer.start();
    };



/**
                     * Ticket has been clicked
                     */
                    SceneMain.prototype.onTicketClicked = function (e) {
                        // score anim
                        // this._$scoreValue.removeClass("score_throb");
                        // remove the ticket
                        var ticket = e.target;
                        ticket.kill();
                        // increase score
                        this._score++;
                        this._$scoreValue.text(this._score);
                        // score anim
                        //this._$scoreValue.addClass("score_throb");
                    };
```

Comment: maybe you should precise how this function is bound to the click event, it might be the important part of the problem

Comment: thanks, i've just aded the start function which may be important, does that help?

Comment: sorry i've been busy, is it made with prototype-js? if yes, your flag is not the good one. Never worked with it, so i didn't find anything helpful for your problem, sorry again